# ¿Como importar un archivo css usando dompdf?

Tags: php, html, laravel, dompdf

estoy utilizando Laravel 8.x y ahora me encuentro intentando realizar un reporte pdf con la librería barryvdh/laravel-dompdf.

Intento agregar uno de mis archivos css de esta manera:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/Cliente/reporte.css') }}">
```

Mi archivos reporte.css ya se encuentra en la carpeta public/css/Cliente/

El problema es que al intentar generar el reporte tarda demasiado en generarlo, y cuando al fin lo logra, no toma las reglas css que hay dentro de `reporte.css` , tampoco funciona con imagenes ni con otro tipo de recursos.

He intentado también de esta manera y tampoco funciona.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('css/Cliente/reporte.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No te lo recomiendo en realidad. Es mejor hacer el estilo css dentro del mismo archivo del cual quieres imprimir. Dompdf da conflictos muchas veces con estilos externos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando uso el dompdf el que me funciona siempre es insertar el código CSS directo en el head ya que así funciona al 100%.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
       p {
         color: red;
       }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Pero abecés también me funciona indicando la ruta absoluta del archivo, pero de este modo no me funciona siempre.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="var/www/project/public/css/Cliente/reporte.css" type="text/css" media="all">


</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```